# SIM card in New Zealand with unlimited internet access

Tags: cellphones, internet, data-plans, new-zealand

Are there any SIM cards with unlimited internet access available in New Zealand, for a stay period of 3 weeks?

Vodaphone counter at Auckland Airport don't offer any unlimited bundles, and I wonder if there are any available in Christchurch.

Comment: Do you really need unlimited? You may well have more luck if you estimate your needs, and buy a large+limited package

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is NZ we're talking about.  It's still lagging with a smaller population in terms of technology up-take and bandwidth capacity.

As such, currently, **there are no unlimited data plans in NZ** for mobile phones (Orcon has introduced them for broadband internet at home).  Why? You can read the whole discussion about what might be required for this to happen on [NZ's GeekZone site](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/forums.asp?forumid=40&topicid=108647).

The best you're going to be able to do, as a friend did earlier this month, is the $19 plans for 500MB from 2degrees, Vodafone or Telecom.  I'd recommend 2degrees IF staying in the cities - I used it in Christchurch in Oct/Nov this year, however if you're going outside the major cities, Vodafone may be a better bet as they have much better coverage.

Enjoy Christchurch, it's my home town! :)

Comment: Be careful is looking at 2degrees.  Whilst the have coverage over much of the country, much of it is via roaming agreements - but by default roaming does not include data, and if you do turn it on then it's not included in the 500MB allowance.

Comment: Yeah, that was my reasoning for saying about if you're going outside the major cities. I went from Christchurch to Geraldine in October and data stopped immediately outside the city - turn it on and you can roam through Vodafone, but then you really may as well just go with Vodafone :/

Comment: Great answer. My wife bought a telecom sim and I bought 2degrees, to maximize coverage. It works - this comment is typed from Queen Charlotte's track!