# SIM cards for New Zealand Visitors

Tags: cellphones, new-zealand

This question is a semi-duplicate of [SIM card in New Zealand with unlimited internet access](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11428/sim-card-in-new-zealand-with-unlimited-internet-access), but that was 7 years ago and I would expect the cellular details have changed in that length of time.

For a two-week visit starting July of next year (2020), what are my options as far as getting a SIM for use in NZ? I have a GSM multiband phone that should work fine on the NZ networks. I'll want data more than voice, but both will be factors. Thanks.

EDIT: I reside in the United States, and this is a USA-standard phone, but it's quad-band and should work with the local nets.

Comment: Puzzled about the mark as duplicate. The question @JonathonReezSupportsMonica considers to be the same as mine is a generic-to-the-point-of-uselessness one that is answered by a two-year-old web site recommendation and nothing else. The answer from Moo below is already much more useful to me than that (although I will still check out the site linked). Note that searches like my own (for a specific country) will never find the absurd generic question linked, as indeed my own did not.

Comment: Where are you traveling from?  If from the US have you considered [Google Fi](https://fi.google.com/about/)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @MIdavalo. I'll edit the question to show where I'm traveling from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Skinny](https://www.skinny.co.nz/), a company which uses the Spark network (which means NZ is very well covered by them) have a [$20NZD a week unlimited plan](https://www.skinny.co.nz/pricing/plans/#combo_weekly) (data, voice, texts) on pay-as-you-go (but it comes with a slowdown after 10GB of usage per billing cycle), and on other plans have an option for "[data binge](https://www.skinny.co.nz/pricing/databinge/)" which is unlimited data per use, and a 12 hour data binge costs you $4.

Sims cost a few dollars at most supermarkets and general grocery retailers (often called dairies/dairy's here in NZ - spelling noted).

Top up can be done via an app, text message, automated phone call.